# Python: Cannot get returned values from functions

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pycharm, firebase-admin

this is my python code. There is no error but the `value` and `value1` variables are not returned after the two defined functions `stream_handler` and `stream_handler1`. I manually set both `Fall_Detection_Status` and `Fall_Detection_Status1` variables from firebase to `1` (refer to the last two lines in the code), but the response at the end of the code is not printing `print(response['publishId'])` so I think the last `if` statement is never getting `value=1` and `value1=1`. Where should be the problem?

```
value = 0
value1 = 0


def stream_handler(message):
    global value
    value = 0
    print(message)
    if message['data'] is 1:
        value = 1
        return value


def stream_handler1(message1):
    global value1
    value1 = 0
    print(message1)
    if message1['data'] is 1:
        value1 = 1
        return value1


if value is 1 & value1 is 1:
        response = pn_client.publish(
            interests=['hello'],
            publish_body={
                'apns': {
                    'aps': {
                        'alert': 'Hello!',
                    },
                },
                'fcm': {
                'notification': {
                    'title': 'Notification',
                    'body': 'Fall Detected !!',
                    },
                },
            },
        )
        print(response['publishId'])


my_stream = db.child("Fall_Detection_Status").stream(stream_handler)
my_stream1 = db.child("Fall_Detection_Status1").stream(stream_handler1)
```

Comment: you are returning value only when the if condition is true

Comment: Don't use `is` when you mean `==`, and don't use `&` when you mean `and`.

Comment: There are various problems with that code. But apart from the issues already mentioned, and your unnecessary use of globals, are you sure that `message['data']` and `message1['data']` contain integers and not strings?

Comment: Curiously, when `value` and `value1` are both equal to 1 then `value is 1 & value1 is 1` actually evaluates to 1, so it _is_ true-ish.

Comment: @DavidZemens I _think_ they're supposed to be callbacks.

Comment: @Moustapha, please see this when you have sometime, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Okay I fixed that and the problem was really the if statement. I tried replacing the if statement in the functions. So I copied and paste it twice in the code; the first one inside the function stream_handler and the second one inside the function stream_handler1... It worked and the code is able to read the messages ! :)

Comment: @akshat Done, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

`is` operator is not a value comparison operator, you need to use `==` here.

`is` compares identities, whereas `==` compares values

Similarly, `&` is also not same as `and`.

`&` is used to "AND" operations whereas `and` is used for combine multiple conditions

Finally, your `return` statements are inside `if` loop, it should be outside:

```
if message['data'] is 1:
    value = 1
return value
```

same for for `message1` and `value1`

Comment: `&` is called the bitwise and operator. It will happen to do the right thing if both values are booleans, but should not be used where `and` is desired. I wouldn't say "& is also same as and".

Comment: @AlexHall, that was mistyped, wanted to say "not same as". Corrected now. thanks for pointing out